# Leetcode 426. Convert Binary Search Tree to Sorted Doubly Linked List?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list, inorder

I am very confused about the question No.426 on leetcode, as I think my answer is right. But after running it shows I am wrong. Below is the question and my original answer:

[image]

[image]

```
"""
# Definition for a Node.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left, right):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
"""
class Solution:
    def treeToDoublyList(self, root):
        """
        :type root: Node
        :rtype: Node
        """
        if root:
            sign = True
            stack = []
            node = root

            while stack or node:
                if node:
                    stack.append(node)
                    node = node.left 
                else:
                    node = stack.pop()

                    if sign:
                        pre,head = node, node
                    else:
                        pre.right = node
                        node.left = pre
                        pre = node

                    node = node.right

            head.left = pre
            pre.right = pre

            return head
        else:
            return None
```

Could someone help me to figure out what's wrong with my codes? Any comment or suggestion will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems with the code.

First is that inside your `if sign:` block you need to set `sign = False` since you only want to initialize `head` once and execute that block only the first time. (Not sure why the variable is called `sign`, perhaps `first` would be more appropriate, or just reusing a `head = None` for that condition would have worked too.)

The second bug is smaller and affects the last link in the list to make it circular. You want to set `pre.right = head` instead of `pre`, so that the last node of the list points back at the first, not at itself.

I haven't really tested this, so it's possible I'm missing something, but it looks to me that this should be enough to fix this code.

Comment: Oops, how careless I am. After revising, it works. Commonly, I used to copy my codes and paste into VS code for debugging step by step. But for those problems regarding binary tree, inputs are difficult to be created. So may I ask what would you usually do to debug those problems quickly?

Comment: @Aurora Glad that fixed it! In this case, I saw a red flag when I noticed variable `sign` not changing through the script, and for the second part I thought for the typical case you don't have a node pointing at itself. Sometimes a fresh set of eyes looking at code is useful! VS Code is a great tool for debugging. Being able to debug code in your head (methodically going through each line, keeping a table of current variable of each variable) is a lot of work but it's a valuable skill. It takes practice, so maybe try to exercise it whenever you can.